# How to create a JTable cell containing Image hyperlink?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, event-listener

I'm trying to find out how to create a `JTable` cell which contains Image, which should be clickable like an hyperlink. I'm able to load Image using default image renderer.

[image: My table with expected image hyperlinks in the last column]

Can somebody explain me how to add hyperlink (mouse listener) for the each image (cell) in the last column of my table? so that, when the image link in jTable cell is clicked, I want it to open a pop-up with some message showing the error message.

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 5):

To launch link in machine's default browser:

```
URI uri = null;
try {
    uri = new URI(urlToOpen);
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    System.out.println("Malformed URI: " + uri);
}
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
    desktop.browse(uri);
} catch (IOException e2) {
    // If the user default browser is not found, or it fails
    // to be launched, or the default handler application
    // failed to be launched
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "The application could not find any compatible browser.");
}
```

You can do this on click of Image.

---

Edit based on comments:

Add listener to image and then you can open a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) or [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) on click of Image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question to be more specific about my requirement. I'm not sure this can be customized to my situation. your comments?

Comment: @merlachandra so do you want to open a popup on click of image?

Comment: I'm not able to add Mouse listener for each individual cell (image) of my last column as in attached Image, can you help me for this?

Comment: @merlachandra can't you add listener in renderer?, I'm not sure if its the good practice or not.

Comment: For displaying the image, I'm using default renderer provided by jtable. Can you explain me in more detail how to add listner in renderer? And ofcourse I'm Java begginner :)

Comment: @If you have time, Shall we have a chat conversation?